# Symfony 2 BDD Behat context "I am not logged in"

Tags: symfony, bdd, behat

How can I manualy make sure that user is not logged in my FeatureContext class in BDD Behat scenario? For example I have this scenario:

```
Scenario: passing wrong values will not get me in
Given I am on "/login"
And I am not logged in
When I fill in "login" with "KtokolwiekWidzialKtokolwiekWie"
When I fill in "password" with "root_as_allways"
When I press "Login"
Then I should be on "/"
And I should see "Wrong login or password"
```

And I've defined this context:

```php
/**
 * @Given /^I am not logged in$/
 */
public function iAmNotLoggedIn()
{
    # logout currently login user, if any
    $request = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('request');
    $request->getSession()->invalidate();
}
```

But this gives me an error when running this feature test.

> You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").

**Note:** I'm using Symfony 2.1 RC-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just visit "/logout" and you will be logged out. Do this before you go to "/login"

Comment: Hm could this be done in "Given" section? As I want to test login action and be sure that in the beggining Im not logged in?

Comment: Sure. just add a given I am on "/logout" before the given I am on "/login"

Comment: Don't do that. Instead of adding it in your feature file, do either what @Inori suggested or return new Then('I am on "/logout"') from you iAmNotLoggedIn() step. Your features should be described in your domain language and you should avoid implementation details  (you shouldn't be changing all the scenarios just because you changed the logout url).

Comment: If you are doing I am on "/login" you might as well do I am on "/logout". I agree that lnori answer is better but I adapted my answer to what was already being done

Answer (score 4):

Here's the custom step you can use:

```
/**
 * @Given /^I am not logged in$/
 */
public function iAmNotLoggedIn()
{
    $this->getMink()
        ->getSession()
        ->visit($this->locatePath('/logout'))
    ;
}
```

But you probably need to update your steps order:

```
Given I am not logged in
  And I am on "/login"
```